# Get Downloaded File Path In Android Application

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, intel-xdk

I am building an Android App Using **HTML5+Cordova** in **IntelXDK**. I am downloading a file using HTML5 as shown below.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = "This Is The Inner Text Of File.";
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = "MyFileName.txt";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }
    downloadLink.click();


    // alert(filesavedat);    // <<<--- Need the downloaded file path here
}
</script>
```

I have no idea weather user have only internal memory or SD card too and have no idea about his/her default download folder. I want to get the path of this file wherever the user device save it after downloading in my JavaScript code(variable). Is this possible or not? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

In native app developing, you can use the following method to access to the download directory.

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Essentially in Cordova file API, there must be some methods doing this in the backend.